# First Android app - cycling through list, one at a time

Tags: android

I'm starting my first real Android app, and I have some beginner questions.
I'm an experienced C# developer, but this is my first time working with Android.

I've designed the screens, and I'm starting on the first one.  It seems that there should be a straight-forward way to do what I would like...

The data model is pretty simple: it's a list of objects, and each top-level object contains a list of sub-objects.  I'd like the first screen to have the current top-level object with a previous and next button; only the current top-level is displayed.  The sub-objects for that top-level are also displayed.

When the next or previous button is pushed, I'd like to cycle to the next/previous top-level object, and of course refresh the list of sub-objects.

I think this could be done with two Buttons, a TextView and a ListView or GridView, but I'm wondering if there's a better way - maybe a control that I don't know about.  It feels like I should have an Adapter and bind the control to this Adapter.

Also, it it ok to do this all in a view?  Fragments seem a bit over-kill here.
And, lastly, is it reasonable to have a simple object hierarchy like:

```
public class SubObject {
    private String _name;
    ... other properties, get/set methods, etc.
}

public class TopLevel {

    private String _name;
    private List<SubObject> _subObjects;
    ....
}
```

Any help, suggestions or examples are appreciated!  Thanks!

Phil

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean is it ok to do this all in an Activity (a view is a single on screen item-  a single button, a single text view, etc).  Yes, that's perfectly fine, if you don't want to have separate screen areas that fragments give you don't use them.

Android doesn't really have Adapters as you think of them.  The only Adapter it has is used to map positions to views in a ListView/GridView/ViewPager.  It isn't used for other views at all.  But you seem to have the right way of doing things.  You could use Fragments and a ViewPager to do this as well, and then you'd switch fragments on next/previous buttons and each fragment would initialize itself once.  But its a matter of preference, neither is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In Android, the recommended UI pattern for multi level data display is to use Master detail (and recursive sub-master-detail) layouts [as explained here.](http://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/descendant-lateral.html) If you chose to follow this pattern, Fragments are necessary, along with a [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) and a [`FragementPagerAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) for full implementation.

But if you choose to use a simple layout like: a header and a content view with next and previous buttons, Fragments are not necessary. You can just replace data in header and content view on button navigation. For data you can use a Database Cursor, or your own data model class.

Comment: Master/Detail is good for some UIs.  It's not good for others, and its absolutely horrible on low end phones (really, a master/detail on an HVGA phone is unreadable).  I find it hard to read even on my note 2, personally I think it sucks for anything smaller than a 7 inch tablet.  Its one thing to say that the right way to implement a master/detail UI is fragments-  you're right, its what its made for.  Its another to say outright that its always the way to show hierarchial data- it may be, but there's plenty of reasons to use other UIs.

Comment: @GabeSechan That only happens when developer just uses dual-pane layout everywhere, for smaller screens, app is supposed to show either the list or the detail, never both.